# ModalPopupExtender's TargetControlID causes postbacks

Tags: asp.net

I've copied some working code using a `ModalPopupExtender` from a working page, and added it to a new page I'm developing.

When the `<asp:Button ID="btnCountry" Text="..." runat="server" />` which is the `TargetControlID` on my new page is clicked, it causes 3 postbacks to the server, and doesn't display the modal `asp:Panel`.

Neither page uses an `asp:UpdatePanel` and I can't work out why my new page does the postbacks when the original page works perfectly....

Any ideas, please?

EDIT: The part of the script which is erroring is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {var fn = function() {$get("MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior, {"BackgroundCssClass":"modalBackground","CancelControlID":"btnCancelCountry","Drag":true,"DropShadow":true,"PopupControlID":"MainContent_panelPopupCountry","PopupDragHandleControlID":"PopupHeaderCountry","dynamicServicePath":"/ChangeDetails","id":"MainContent_ModalPopupExtenderCountry"}, null, null, $get("MainContent_btnCountry"));
});
//]]>
</script>
```

The red line begins at the `.UI` element, and the console shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined
```

whereas the working page shows this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {var fn = function() {$get("MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();
var Page_ValidationActive = false;
if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {
    ValidatorOnLoad();
}

function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
    if (Page_ValidationActive) {
        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
        //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What is "ModalPopupExtender"?

Comment: There is not much info to go on here. Are there any javascript errors in the browser console that could be causing the problem?